# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Identity has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have problem with Identity ASP.net Core 2.1. I create Role in startup.cs. When running display error

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered.)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
>   ContosoUniversity.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in Startup.cs
>   +
>               CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Statup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using ContosoUniversity.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace ContosoUniversity
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));

            //services.AddIdentity<ContosoUniversityUser, IdentityRole>()
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            //     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
            CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
        }
        public async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            //adding custom roles
            var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            //serviceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ContosoUniversityUser>>();
            string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Manager", "Member" };
            IdentityResult roleResult;
            foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
                if (!roleExist)
                {
                    roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                }
            }
            var poweruser = new ContosoUniversityUser
            {
                UserName = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"],
                Email = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]
            };

            string UserPassword = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserPassword"];
            var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]);

            if (_user == null)
            {
                var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, UserPassword);
                if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to check InnerException for more details on this error

Comment: Share us code related with configuring `Identity` in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use [asp.net-identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) without registering it with your container.

In the configure-service method uncomment these lines

```
services.AddIdentity<ContosoUniversityUser, IdentityRole>();
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now the serviceprovider will know about these services because that [extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/07774234a652b9ceb2aa5cc50167dda8b15aeb55/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L44) registers them for you.

Also don't forget to migrate your database so it knows about the user, roles and so on.

Comment: If I uncommnet above line, the system will display.                                         
>An error occurred while starting the application.
InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(string name, Action<AuthenticationSchemeBuilder> configureBuilder)

InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application

Answer (score 1):

I try to add below code in ConfigureServices. This can help me to run:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ContosoUniversityUser>(opt =>
        {
            // Configure Password Options
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        }
        );
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<IdentityRole>>();
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ContosoUniversityUser>>();
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: error display: >An error occurred while starting the application. InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(string name, Action<AuthenticationSchemeBuilder> configureBuilder) InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application

Comment: You need to remove the code related with `services.AddIdentity` in `Startup`. Check the [result](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hgyLwMGzT-z18aRj)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you achieve `Identity` by `Asp.Net Core Identity Library`.

You could check your project to find **ProjectName->Areas->Identity->IdentityHostingStartup**. Change `Configure` like below:

```
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<CoreAppContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoreAppContextConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<ContosoUniversityUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CoreAppContext>();
        });
    }
}
```

Update

For the root cause, it is that `services.AddDefaultIdentity` did not add `IdentityRole` to `IServiceCollection`, check this source code [IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/UI/IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.cs) which call [AddIdentityCore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Core/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L31).

Try below code.

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ContosoUniversityUser>()
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() // Add IdentityRole to ServiceCollection
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I fix same you, but is not run : public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection")));

                services.AddIdentity<ContosoUniversityUser,IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
            });
        }

Comment: Could you share us a project to reproduce or the code related with your identity?